# Algorithm to perform adaptive quality control for videos?

Tags: video-quality

0

I recently had an interview experience that was un-aligned with my software engineering experience, but I still think want to get a better understanding of what the interviewer was asking, which I didn't really understand at the time.

Basically, I was given a design and implementation question where I was supposed to design/scope out the APIs to query a video manifest file, and another set of APIs that controls a video player. In terms of the interview itself, I only had to design what the APIs returned, and didn't have to implement the APIs.

The goal is to achieve adaptive quality control using known network conditions and video playback progress for some live stream/video using the APIs that I designed, and I was supposed to implement the adaptive quality control part.

This was a 45 minute interview and was meant to be an implementation question (which I didn't really get to because I was stuck on the design part due to not having any knowledge of this topic area).

My question is what are the complexities when it comes to implementation such a system? What data structures and algorithms are necessary? I would like to understand better some basic adaptive algorithms as it applies here.